# How to implement a Navigation Drawer at the top of the screen instead of showing from the sides

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I want to implement a `Navigation Drawer` showing from top half of the screen instead of showing it from sides of the screen. How can we implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Drawer menu showing from top]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using library.
Try to use [DobSliding](https://github.com/Startappz/DobSliding), I think it's what you want